# The name '$' does not exist in the current scope - typescript and jquery inside a module

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Im getting an error when trying to use jquery inside a class or module:

```
/// <reference path="../jquery.d.ts" />

element: jQuery; // all is good
elementou: $;    // all is fine



class buggers{
    private element: jQuery;   // The name jQuery does not exist in the current scope
    private elementou: $;      // The name $ does not exist in the current scope
}

module something {
    class buggers{
        private element: jQuery;   // The name jQuery does not exist in the current scope
        private elementou: $;      // The name $ does not exist in the current scope
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Try using `window.$`. All globals are members of `window` in JavaScript.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 `window` only exists in JavaScript in web browsers.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Jquery only exists in web browsers.

Comment: @MathSquared11235 You can use [jQuery](http://www.hacksparrow.com/jquery-with-node-js.html) in [other platforms](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery) too...

Comment: I am no typescript expert, but typescript compiles to javascript right? Could you in that case show the actual code, rather than this... 'thing'. (In general this is the exact problem with "compiles to" systems or too far fetching frameworks: you lose sight of how it works, but that's besides the point)

Comment: In this case the problem was the famous in-between-the-chair-and-the-screen. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$` and `jQuery` as if they were types. Taking the `d.ts` from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts), the type you are looking for is either `JQuery` or `JQueryStatic`

`$` and `jQuery` should already be declared vars in the `d.ts` file:

```
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

... but if you feel you need to declare them again in your class, you might want to try:

```
class buggers{
    private element: JQuery;   // JQuery object. You'll need to assign something to this before you can use it. e.g element = $('selector');
    private elementou: JQueryStatic;      // Reference to the $ JQuery Static object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you did this, but I had overlooked this important step.  Remember to include the definition reference at the top of your TS file.

```
/// <reference path="../../assets/js/libs/typedefs/jquery-1.8.d.ts" />
```